# Inputlines must be converted to tuples

Tags: python, input, readlines

I have an input file that looks as follows:

`4 * 2 ^ 3 + 4 ^ 1
 2 * 1 ^ 2 + 2 ^ 3`

and there could be more lines. What I need to do is to extract the value that is before the `*` sign, so for the first line that is the `4`. Then I need to make a tuple `g = [(2,3),(4,1)]`, so the tuple-pairs are separated by the `+` and then the pair itself by the `^`.

```
my_input = open('input.txt').readlines()
lines = [str(line) for line in 
open('input.txt','r').read().split('\n')]
per_line = str(lines[0]).split('*')
x = int(per_line[0])
terms = str(per_line[1].split('+'))
```

Now if i `print terms` I get `['2 ^ 3 ', ' 4 ^ 1']`, and if I `print x` I get `4`, so that seems to work. But now I need to get those values in the described tuple-form. If I split again on `'^'` I don't get the result needed, but instead `["['2 ", " 3 ', ' 4 ", " 1']"]`, which isn't workable. I tried it with `factors = str(terms.split('^'))`.

Also I need to make this an iteration so it works for all the lines, but I can do that later. I first want to make sure it works for just the first line.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `If I split again on '^' I don't get the result needed`. Please show your code.

Comment: `factors = str(terms.split('^'))`

Comment: Why do you use `str` everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a better way to do it:

```
import re

x = []
g = []
with open('input.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        nums = re.split(r'[\*\^\+]', line)
        x.append(int(nums[0]))
        g.append((int(nums[1]), int(nums[2])))

print(x) # [4, 2]
print(g) # [(2, 3), (1, 2)]
```

Comment: Nice, never knew you could split on multiple characters in one line, very neat :)

Answer (score 1):

> Now if i `print terms` I get `['2 ^ 3 ', ' 4 ^ 1']`

Then for each value (string) in `terms` you have to split on '^', then cast each result to int and pack into tuple:

```
g = [tuple(map(int, x.split('^'))) for x in terms]
```

which is

1. taking each string, eg. `'2 ^ 3 '`
2. splitting it into a list, eg. `['2 ',  '3 ']`
3. applying `int` function to each list element with `map`
4. making tuple of the mapping result

Answer (score 1):

I would first collect all of the numbers in the string, assign them to their respective tuples, then assign them to a list.

```
my_input = open('input.txt').readlines()
lines = [str(line) for line in
open('input.txt','r').read().split('\n')]
per_line = str(lines[0]).split('*')
x = int(per_line[0])
terms = str(per_line[1].split('+'))

#Start Soln Here ->
to_parse = terms.replace('^', ',')
#Tuples to populate final list g
a = ()
b = ()
#To hold int-converted values from file stream
operands = []
for i in to_parse:
    if i.isdigit():
        operands.append(int(i))
    #to prevent the inclusion of operators.
    else:
        continue
#operands list is populated now... Last thing to do is assign them to your tuples!
a = operands[0], operands[1]
b = operands[2], operands[3]
g = [a,b]
#test output
print(g)
```

Returns

```
[(2, 3), (4, 1)]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

It's a bit of a chatterbox solution but it should get the job done

Answer (score 1):

If you're parsing general expressions, you might want to construct a parse tree instead:

```
from lark import Lark

parser = Lark('''
    ?sum: product
        | sum "+" product       -> add
        | sum "-" product       -> sub

    ?product:
        | product "*" exponent  -> mul
        | product "/" exponent  -> div
        | exponent

    ?exponent:
        | item "^" exponent     -> exp
        | item

    ?item: NUMBER               -> number
        | "-" item              -> neg
        | "(" sum ")"

    %import common.NUMBER
    %import common.WS
    %ignore WS''', start='sum')

s = '4 * 2 ^ 3 + 4 ^ 1'
tree = parser.parse(s)
print(tree.pretty())
```

Which results in:

```
add
  mul
    number      4
    exp
      number    2
      number    3
  exp
    number      4
    number      1
```

Comment: I was unfamiliar with this type of parsing trees. Thanks for the insight :)